# Horizontal fling in vertical ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, swipe

I have a fragment that shows the statistic of my app, and I want it that when the user does a horizontal fling from left to rigth or right to left, change data from days to months, from months to years...

The xml of my Fragment is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.devadvance.circulartest"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollViewProgreso"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#55b5c2"
tools:ignore="NewApi,UnusedNamespace" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutProgreso"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#55b5c2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgpqprogreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/iconoprogreso" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutprogreso"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
        android:background="#55b5c2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtpqprogreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgpqprogreso"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="¿Por qué?"
        android:textColor="#394347" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txmesprogreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgpqprogreso"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="MAYO"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtsemanaprogreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txmesprogreso"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="SEMANA 2"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnizq"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtsemanaprogreso"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtsemanaprogreso"
        android:background="@drawable/flecha" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnderecha"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnizq"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtsemanaprogreso"
        android:background="@drawable/flecha" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/porcentajetrabajo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/porcentajerojo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/porcentajerojo"
        android:text="TRABAJO"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicadoramarillo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indicadornaranja"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/porcentajeamarillo"
        android:src="@drawable/indicadoramarillo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/porcentajeamarillo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/porcentajerojo"
        android:layout_below="@id/porcentajerojo"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="44sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/porcentajedescanso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/porcentajeamarillo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/porcentajetrabajo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:text="DESCANSO"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/porcentajerojo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicadoramarillo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="44sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicadornaranja"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutprogreso"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/porcentajerojo"
        android:src="@drawable/indicadornaranja" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgllama"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/porcentajeamarillo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/llama" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kcalprogreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgllama"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="44sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtkcalquemadas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kcalprogreso"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="KCAL QUEMADAS"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgsensacionprogreso"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtkcalquemadas"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/regular" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sensacionmedia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgsensacionprogreso"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="SENSACIÓN MEDIA"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtsensacionprogreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sensacionmedia"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#394347"
        android:textSize="44sp" />

     </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

And the code I'm using to detect the horizontal Fling is the following:

```
private final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

  private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

      private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        }

     @Override
     public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
             float arg3) {
         return false;
     }



   }
```

And at onCreateView:

```
layoutpro.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, final MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
         switch (event.getAction()) 
         {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    break;
         }
     return true;
    }

});
```

Where layoutpro is

```
layoutpro = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutProgreso);
```

The fling gesture works but only sometimes, because most of the time it detects it as a vertical scroll movement, so, what could I do to keep both gestures working fine?

Comment: return false in onTouch

Comment: It works perfect with that correction.

Comment: sure it does, otherwise I wouldn't comment ;)